# How do I play DVDs fullscreen on an external monitor in Lion?

Tags: macos, mission-control, dvd, fullscreen

MacbookPro6,2 running Mac OS Lion 10.7.2 attempting to run a DVD fullscreen on an external monitor.  My laptop display is primary, but I would like the DVD to run fullscreen on the External (a lovely 23"-er).

I'm fine with using VLC if that's necessary, but I prefer to not make the external monitor my primary display. #ihateyoumissioncontrol

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/32332/7833.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run VLC.

In VLC, go to the Video menu and the Fullscreen Video Device menu and choose which screen you want to use for fullscreen video playback.

[image]

Comment: Incidentally, VLC will fullscreen on whatever display that it is running.

Comment: I thought that I had.  Rectified...

Comment: gracias señor! 1..2..3..

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to mirror the display to the second monitor. I did this in a pinch the other day when I stumbled upon this wonderful, *ahem*, feature of Apple's DVD Player